# How to find string data-type that includes a number in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, string, numeric

I have a DataFrame with two columns. One column contain string values that may or may not include numbers (integer or float).

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [('A', '>10'),
        ('B', '10'),
        ('C', '<10'),
        ('D', '10'),
        ('E', '10-20'),
        ('F', '20.0'),
        ('G', '25.1') ]

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'value'])
```

Entries in Column `value` have string data-type. But, their values might be numeric or not.

**What I want to get:**

- Find which rows have numeric values in column `value`.
- Remove other rows from dataset.

Final result will look like:

```
name    value    
'B'      10         
'D'      10 
'F'      20.0  
'G'      25.1
```

I tried to use `isnumeric()` function but it returns `True` only for integers (not float).

If you have any idea to solve this problem, please let me know.

---

**Updated Question (multi columns):**

(The same question when there are more than one column with numeric values)

Similarly, I have a DataFrame with three columns. Two columns contain string values that may or may not include numbers (integer or float).

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [('A', '>10', 'ABC'),
        ('B', '10', '15'),
        ('C', '<10', '>10'),
        ('D', '10', '15'),
        ('E', '10-20', '10-30'),
        ('F', '20.0', 'ABC'),
        ('G', '25.1', '30.1') ]

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'value1', 'value2'])
```

Entries in Columns `value1` & `value2` have string data-type. But, their values might be numeric or not.

**What I want to get:**

- Find which rows have numeric values in columns `value1` & `value2`.
- Remove other rows from dataset.

Final result will look like:

```
name    value1    value2
'B'      10         15
'D'      10         15 
'G'      25.1       30.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`, then [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to remove the invalid rows:

```
(data_df.assign(value=pd.to_numeric(data_df['value'], errors='coerce'))
        .dropna(subset=['value'])
)
```

*NB. this upcasts the integers into floats, but this is the way Series works and it's better to have upcasting than forcing an object type*

output:

```
  name  value
1    B   10.0
3    D   10.0
5    F   20.0
6    G   25.1
```

If you just want to slice the rows **and keep the string type**:

```
data_df[pd.to_numeric(data_df['value'], errors='coerce').notna()]
```

output:

```
  name value
1    B    10
3    D    10
5    F  20.0
6    G  25.1
```

###### updated question (multi columns)

build a mask and use `any`/`all` prior to slicing:

```
mask = data_df[data_df.columns[1:]].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notna().all(1)
data_df[mask]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way that I can use string data-type for name of column in function "assign". I mean; data_df.assign('value'=.....).  I have several columns and I want to use a For loop for all columns, instead of repeating this command for every column.

Comment: @Mohammad can you update your question with an example of multi-column data (or maybe open a new question that references this one)

Comment: Sorry for trouble. I edited the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mohammad check the update (and please add your new example as an addendum at the end of your question, not replacing the original data, this avoid invalidating the first part of my answer)