# Find string data-type that includes a number in Pandas DataFrame and change the type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. One or more than one column contain string values that may or may not include numbers (integer or float).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [('A', '>10', 'ABC'),
        ('B', '10', '15'),
        ('C', '<10', '>10'),
        ('D', '10', '15'),
        ('E', '10-20', '10-30'),
        ('F', '20.0', 'ABC'),
        ('G', '25.1', '30.1') ]

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'value1', 'value2'])
```

I am looking for a method to check each of the cells inside the dataframe if there is any value which is assigned as strings but contains numerical(integer or float) value and then change it to integer or float by keeping the whole dataframe intact(not changing it to array)

so far, I found "[How to find string data-type that includes a number in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70681047/how-to-find-string-data-type-that-includes-a-number-in-pandas-dataframe)" article on stackoverflow useful, but this article is guided to drop the numerical values stored as string types.

Comment: Can you add expected ouput from sample data?

Comment: Thanks for replying @jezrael. Yes I can add expected output

Answer (score 0):

If need all values numeric repalce non numeric to missing values:

```
data_df.iloc[:, 1:] = data_df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
print (data_df)
  name value1 value2
0    A    NaN    NaN
1    B   10.0   15.0
2    C    NaN    NaN
3    D   10.0   15.0
4    E    NaN    NaN
5    F   20.0    NaN
6    G   25.1   30.1
```

If need replace missing values to original strings:

```
data_df.iloc[:, 1:] = (data_df.iloc[:, 1:]
                              .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
                              .fillna(data_df.iloc[:, 1:]))
print (data_df)
  name value1 value2
0    A    >10    ABC
1    B   10.0   15.0
2    C    <10    >10
3    D   10.0   15.0
4    E  10-20  10-30
5    F   20.0    ABC
6    G   25.1   30.1
```

But then get mixed types numeric with strings:

```
print (data_df.iloc[:, 1:].applymap(type))
            value1           value2
0    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
1  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>
2    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
3  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>
4    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
5  <class 'float'>    <class 'str'>
6  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>
```

EDIT:

```
cols = data_df.select_dtypes(object).columns.difference(['name'], sort=False)
data_df[cols] = data_df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str.strip(), errors='coerce'))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your code suggestion worked, but the number of columns increased and when I am trying to pass the dataframe through one-hot encoding, showing a bunch of errors which wasn't the case before

Comment: @UnFury - hmm, can you add expected ouput after `one-hot encoding` ? And your code what use?

Comment: I believe it was a kernel issue due to which it wasn't running at first. after implementing `data_df.iloc[:, 1:] = data_df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`, it changes all the numerical values stored as strings to NaN(which I wasn't expecting to do so, since I wanted to change the data type of the column which contains such values only).

Comment: @UnFury - `it changes all the numerical values stored as strings to Nan` - hmm, problem is with data in question? for me working perfectly (still waiting for expected ouput)

Comment: I am working with dataframe of shape 25673 * 45 so don't know exactly how to share the expected output here. but my main motive is to convert all the cells in a dataframe which are originally assigned with string type but contains numerical values to convert it to integer or float type.

Comment: @UnFury - So problem is with real data? Then is problem something else, because solution with sample data working perfectly. Only way is change sample data for see what failed by real data.

Comment: Oh I see. Is there any way of changing the datatype of columns to integer or float type which were originally assigned with string type?

Comment: @UnFury - Do you think something else like my answer? I think not.

Comment: @UnFury `it changes all the numerical values stored as strings to Nan` - if check data is possible some values has trailing spaces like `' 10'` instead `'10'` ?

Comment: @UnFury - try change `data_df.iloc[:, 1:] = data_df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` to `data_df.iloc[:, 1:] = data_df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str.strip(), errors='coerce'))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am now seeing a different error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`. Since I can't share you the expected output here, I have to find out a solution by my own. Thanks for helping me out. Please do feel free if you have any suggestion regarding to this issue.

Comment: @UnFury - Added `EDIT` - only strings columns strip spaces and assign back numeric, added `difference` for omit first `name` column